# cannot ping smart watch- model DA08

Tags: tcp, wear-os, ping, tcplistener, wearables

- I was trying to do TCP connection in smart watch
- but I can't ping my watch from laptop using same network and error- connection refused when tcp connection reference from (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sending-and-receiving-data-with-sockets-in-android).
- what can I do for currently and asking for solution
- smart watch model -DA08.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOFyT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently paired with the watch, then the default network is probably bridged over BT.

You could test, while BT is disabled.

Or specifically request wifi network, see https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/network-access#requesting-wifi-connectivity

Comment: hi yuri schimke, I add request wifi network and connect to my own handphone hotspot and close bluetooth and test again but error - connection refused still came out.Beside that, i try to ping smart watch from laptop but Request timed out.. my smart watch ip - 192.168.45.44, laptop -  192.168.45.153

Comment: I'm not certain that watches respond to pings.  I can test myself and see if it works for me.

Comment: Can you connect to the watch, like pairing over wifi?

Comment: solved.. can ping . i can't connect because no port open at pc